# Style element in for repeat, triggered on event

Tags: css, typescript, aurelia

I need to style one table element rendered from a `repeat.for` on a `<td>` tag.

```
<td repeat.for="field of fields" 
  class="${field.fieldKey == 'validTo' ? 'fontweigth: bold;': ''}"> 
  bold field-text here
</td>
```

This is just my inital attempt to check if I can style one of the element repeated(doesn't seem to work).

My intended end result is that the `validTo`-field gets a bold font when an event is triggered. Currently I don't have a good approach for this, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to set a style using the `class` attribute, you should be using the `css` attribute instead. Use `css` instead of `style` to avoid issues with IE & Edge. You have also misspelled `font-weight`.

```
<td repeat.for="field of fields" 
  css="${field.fieldKey == 'validTo' ? 'font-weight: bold;' : ''}">
  bold field-text here
</td>
```

You can also use `style.bind` if you prefer the syntax:

```
<td repeat.for="field of fields" 
  style.bind="field.fieldKey == 'validTo' ? 'font-weight: bold;' : ''">
  bold field-text here
</td>
```

---

A good way to have a style set on a particular HTML element when an event happens, is either to

- Set a property on the object, and toggle that property when that event happens. Think of something like `css="${field.bolded ? 'font-weight: bold;' : ''}"` on your HTML element and then setting `fields[index].bolded = true` in your viewmodel.
- Reference the HTML element using a `ref` attribute, and toggle the styling directly from the viewmodel. You'd have something like `ref="fieldElements[$index]"`, and toggle in the viewmodel: `fieldElements[index].style.fontWeight = 'bold'`

Comment: Now it works, but how can I reference this from my TS file, based on the event?

Comment: I've edited the answer to use the `css` attribute instead of `style`. Binding expressions inside a `style` attribute don't work in IE and some versions of Edge due to the browser removing any invalid CSS from the attribute's value before it is passed to JavaScript code. The `css` attribute shipped with the framework allows you to avoid this issue.